# DRYout a class-based chainable API

Tags: python

I have written a chainable API (in a similar style to jQuery) as follows:

```
class ChainableAPI:
  def show(self):
    self.visibility = 1
    return self

  def goBlue(self):
    self.color = 'Blue'
    return self

  def die(self):
    self.life = 0
    return self

chainableAPI = ChainableAPI()

(chainableAPI
  .goBlue()
  .show()
  .die()
  .goBlue())
```

Notice how each method of `ChainableAPI` ends with `return self`. Is there a way to have all methods to `return self` automatically? That way I do not have to specify `return self` manually for each method.

Comment: I'd recomment ypu to take a look at "aspect oriented" programing - is just a way of ading behavior patterns to functions. There are packages in Python that do it properly, and could do more than the `return self`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a decorator:

```
import functools

def chainable(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        return args[0]
    return decorated
```

Then the class would look like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    @chainable
    def show(self):
        self.visibility = True

    @chainable
    def go_blue(self):
        self.color = 'blue'
```

But is it better than just writing `return self`?

Also, a class decorator could be written to apply the `chainable` decorator to all methods not starting with `_`:

```
def all_chainable(klass):
    for k, v in klass.__dict__.items():
        if not k.startswith('_') and callable(v):
            setattr(klass, k, chainable(v))
    return klass
```

Example:

```
@all_chainable
class Foo(object):
    def show(self):
        self.visibility = True
```

Still, no matter how cool it may be I still think you should just use `return self`. But this shows how powerfull Python is.

Comment: hm.. but you still have to decorate each method, the OP asked for a way to do it for all methods in a class at once..

Comment: @noah1989: you can't do that for *all methods*, because there are methods (such as '__'-methods), that are not supposed to be altered in this way.

Comment: I've added another decorator for wrapping all methods. It skips methods starting with underscore.

Comment: this is super awesome. but I'd rather not use it. :D